# SQL query run in console but not through Laravel query builder

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have a Table called `Sanad` in Microsoft SQL Server which has two columns `bedeh` and `bestan`. I would like to fetch all codes and sum of its bedeh and bestan in Laravel provided that the sum of its bedeh is higher than that of bestan. In addition, the data type of both bedeh and bestan is money. Here is the code I have written for this purpose in Laravel 6:

```
DB::table('t1')
  ->fromSub(function ($query){
    return $query->selectRaw('Code, sum(bedeh) bed, sum(bestan) bes')
      ->from('Sanad')
      ->groupBy('Code');
    }, 't1')
  ->where('bed', '>', 'bes')
  ->get();
```

However, when the code is executed, I come across to the problem below:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax. (SQL: select * from (select Code, sum(bedeh) bed, sum(bestan) bes

What is interesting is that when I copy the resulted query and run it in the Management Studio, it fetches the codes flawlessly. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks,
Habib

Comment: What is the type of your `bedeh` and `bestan` columns?

Comment: The type of both columns is money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my approach: instead of writing a query for the whole process, I divided it into different parts each of which works with Eloquent. To be specific, I selected Code, sum(bedeh), and sum(bestan) by this code:

```
$codes = Sanad::selectRaw('Code, sum(bedeh) bed, sum(bestan) bes')
   ->groupBy('Code')
   ->get();
```

Then, I fetched rows with the higher sum of bedeh by laravel instead of SQL like this:

```
$debtors = array();
foreach ($codes as $c) {
    if($c->bes < $c->bed) {
        $debtors[] = $c->Code;
    }
}
```

Now, we can use another select to get Eloquent instances like this:

```
Person::select(....)->whereIn('Code', $debtors)....->get();
```

The performance may decrease in this scenario; however, I can benefit from Eloquent facilities such as pagination.

Habib

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cast the values in your query i.e.

```
sum(isnull(cast(bedeh as float),0)) as bed, 
sum(isnull(cast(bestanh as float),0)) as bes
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did it, but the only thing that happened was that the error message changed to "Error converting data type nvarchar to float"